# Get Value from Key:Value Pair with variable as input and output

Tags: bash, macos, key-value

I have an array of Department Names and Department Codes in a script.
A user will select a Department Name which is then assigned to a variable; I need to

- read the array (deptCodeArray)
- find the Department Name selected by the user (departmentName)
- get the Department Code matched to the Department Name from the array and set to a variable (deptCode) that will be used later.
  This script is run on remote macOS computers (macOS Big Sur or later) using an MDM tool (Jamf).

```
# This is an array of Department Namse and matching Department Codes embedded 
# in the script. I have full control over this array.

deptCodeArray="
Information Technology=IT,
Marketing=MA,
Finance=FI
"

# The Department Name will be selected by the user when the script runs 
# (The full script includes a user dialog with a menu of department 3 names 
# to select from.)

departmentName="Information Technology"

# The Department Code is the desired output, to be used later in the script.
# In this case it should be deptCode=IT

deptCode=""
```

I've tried a couple of different ways to get this working.
Apparently macOS does not support associative arrays?
I started with "declare -A deptCodeArray" but apparently this requires bash 4, which does not come with macOS, and installing is not an option.

I was trying awk, but I have some trouble understanding how to make that work, and I am not sure if something else would work.
I am also not sure if I have the correct syntax for the array.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses; I will give them a try. If it wasn't blindingly obvious this is my first foray into this type of problem so I was not certain I was formatting my"array" correctly (thank you for clearing that up a bit), or if calling it an array was even accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way how to do it with bash's `=~` operator, which considers the string to the right of it as a regular expression. This example doesn't use arrays, except the `BASH_REMATCH` (a builtin array whose members are assigned by the `=~` operator), and should work in macOS' bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The variable name is misleading. This isn't a bash array
deptCodeArray="
Information Technology=IT,
Marketing=MA,
Finance=FI
"

departmentName="Information Technology"

[[ $deptCodeArray =~ $'\n'"$departmentName"=([^$'\n',]*) ]]
deptCode=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

echo "$deptCode"
```

For more information about `=~` operator, see [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs), the section starting with `[[…]]`. For the `$'…'` construct, see [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)

Comment: Thank you.  knowing there are multiple answers to this question and my relative lack of knowledge, I chose this solution mainly because the final script will have roughly 280 lines for the departments and associated department codes. This solution allowed me to keep the department names and codes on separate lines, this keeping the code more easily readable.

Answer (score 1):

### Under bash v3.2:

.1 Parsing your `$deptCodeArray`:

```bash
deptCodeArray="
Information Technology=IT,
Marketing=MA,
Finance=FI
"

while IFS== read field value;do
    [ -n "$value" ] && printf -v Arry_${field// /_} '%s' "${value%,}"
done <<<"$deptCodeArray"
```

Then, here is array names created by previous command:

```bash
printf '[%s]\n' "${!Arry_@}"
```

```
[Arry_Finance]
[Arry_Information_Technology]
[Arry_Marketing]
```

```bash
declare -p "${!Arry_@}"
```

```
declare -- Arry_Finance="FI"
declare -- Arry_Information_Technology="IT"
declare -- Arry_Marketing="MA"
```

.2 Showing content:

```bash
for var in Information\ Technology Marketing Finance ;do
    nvar=Arry_${var// /_}
    printf '%-25s: %s\n' "$var" "${!nvar}"
done
```

```
Information Technology   : IT
Marketing                : MA
Finance                  : FI
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

deptCodeArray="Information Technology=IT,Marketing=MA,Finance=FI,"

departmentName="Information Technology"

# V1
deptCode=$( echo "$deptCodeArray" | grep -Eo "$departmentName=.+," | cut -d'=' -f2 | cut -d',' -f1 )
echo "V1 $deptCode"

# V2
deptCode=$( echo "$deptCodeArray" | sed "s/.*$departmentName=//;s/,.*//"  )
echo "V2 $deptCode"
```

**For V1**

- the `sed` removes everything before the departmentName.
- the `cut`s keep only what is contained between the `=` and `,`

**For V2**

- the `sed` prints everything between the departmentName and the following `=`

Note

- I modified the deptCodeArray a bit by putting it on one line and having a comma after all items, even the last one.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the number of departments is small (maybe up to 100), a simple linear search of an (integer-)indexed array should be sufficient for your needs.  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

deptCodes=( 'Information Technology'    IT
            'Marketing'                 MA
            'Finance'                   FI )

deptName='Information Technology'

deptCode=''
for ((i=0; i<${#deptCodes[*]}; i+=2)); do
    if [[ ${deptCodes[i]} == "$deptName" ]]; then
        deptCode=${deptCodes[i+1]}
        break
    fi
done

printf '%s\n' "$deptCode"
```

- To avoid fiddly string manipulation for array elements like `'Information Technology=IT'`, the name/code pairs are stored as successive array elements (names at even indices and codes at odd indices) in an array called `deptCodes`.
- The `for ((i=0; i<${#deptCodes[*]}; i+=2)); do` loop steps through the department name/code pairs one at a time.
- The `break` stops the loop if the department name is found because there is no point continuing after that.

The code could become unacceptably slow with a large number of departments.  In that case I'd ensure that the array entries are in sorted order, by department name, and use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: thank you.  This actually will be about 160 Department Names and codes, along with a second similar block of code for Building Names and Building codes, about 50 lines or so.  They will not change frequently.  I may have to update maybe once per year, if that.

Comment: @BenPhilware, a test with a faked array with 160 department names and codes shows that a full scan of the array takes 0.004 seconds on an unexceptional machine (cheap Windows laptop running Cygwin).  Unless you are doing a lot of searches as part of a single run of your program, the simple linear search should be sufficient for your needs.